# How to make a hyperbolic game board with octagonal tiles?

Tags: gm-techniques, battle-map

I'm currently thinking about making a campaign that will feature the far realms, and I've been reading a lot of Lovecraft. To get across the idea of alien geometries, I was considering using some sort of [hyperbolic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyperbolic_geometry) game board preferably [tiled with octagons](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Octagonal_tiling).

Unfortunately, no such game board seems to be available off the shelf, so I was wondering how I could make one or have it made, or at least somehow simulate playing on a hyperbolic plane.

Comment: Do not answer in comments.

Comment: I've edited your question to remove the part where you're asking if something like this already exists, since people seem to have interpreted it as a "shopping question", which are off-topic here. I also added a couple of Wikipedia links for context, since not everyone here may be familiar with hyperbolic geometry.  Feel free to go over my edits and fix anything you don't like.

Comment: You might also find [this question on gamedev.SE](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/54027/why-dont-we-use-octogonal-maps-instead-of-hexagonal-maps) interesting.

Comment: This is more like a [geometry question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) about [hyperbolic tiling](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/917654/good-data-structure-for-hyperbolic-tiling)